# per-directory permission in svn

Tags: svn

I am configuring svn server for a local network. This is file based svn server i'e the host is localhost. I would like to give per-directory permission to my users.The repository is in my account. Is it possible to do on this setup?

```
  svn list file://localhost/path /to repository/in /network
```

It lists the svn repository and as well as checkouts without authenticating the users. I have configured both the passwd and authz file of con directory.Following is the configuration:

```
     [general]
     anon-access = none
     auth-access = write
     password-db = passwd
     authz-db = authz
     realm    = abc
```

SASL is disabled.I have added username and password in the passwd file and I have given per-directory permission in authz file. But this is not working at all. It neither does asks username nor authentcates it. Can you please suggest any ideas for it?

And I have a

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
[users]
username = password
```

in order to limit access to authenticate users only.

Comment: i have used that thing also. it is even not working for me. is it possible to give per directory permission in the file based svn server configuration?

Comment: Personally I use apache and authz in order to achieve directory level access right. Have a look at http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_de/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html . The article is in german, but the configuration example should speak for themselves.